# Where is the source that says that Stiyl looking like an adult was due to art direction mistake?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Where is the source that says that Stiyl looking like an adult was due to art direction mistake?

I remember something about "old" vs. "new", being interpreted wrong...

I think it was on the [Toaru Majutsu no Index Wiki](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com), but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Toaru Majutsu no Index Wiki](https://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Toaru_Majutsu_no_Index_Wiki) does say it, on both [Stiyl Magnus](https://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Stiyl_Magnus#Design_evolution) and [Kanzaki Kaori](https://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kanzaki_Kaori#Design_evolution)'s design evolution sections, but it doesn't actually give citations for its claims. The actual source is from Haimura Kiyotaka, the novels' illustrator, [on his blog](http://r-s.sakura.ne.jp/w/i01.htm). A translation of Stiyl and Kanzaki's sections:

> ※ステイルは当初からイメージのズレが余り有りません。衣装は上からマント・ローブ・黒シャツ黒ズボンとなります。
>
> ちなみに、魔術側のキャラは１巻当時から、科学側のキャラに比べて年齢と外見の差異が著しいですが、 
>   　コレには一応理由があったりします。詳しくは神裂のラフで後述。
>
> There has not been much change in Stiyl's design from the very
>   beginning. From top down, he wears a cape, a robe, a black shirt, and
>   black pants. 
>   By the way, ever since their introduction in Volume 1,
>   the gap between age and appearance in the magic side characters has
>   been much greater than in the science side characters. There is a
>   reason for this. See Kanzaki's rough for more.
>
> ※神裂はパーツが多かったので一番苦労しました。この段階ではジーンズのカットが随分と中途半端です。
>
> （ステイルの項から続き）１巻の本文初稿を読んだとき、はいむらが抱いた印象は、 
>   　「…ああ、これは『オトナの理屈』に子供が反抗する話なんだな」なのでした。 
>   　つまり、１巻時点の魔術側キャラであるステイルと神裂は、主人公である上条の目線からは、 
>   　「子供にとって、嬉しくない建前や理屈を並べる大人」に見えたハズなのです。
>
> 当時はさすがに、『禁書』がココまで長期に続くとは思ってもいなかったので、 
>   　２名は上記の印象に従い、年齢不相応の造型にしました…そして、７巻辺りから徐々にそれを後悔する羽目に。
>
> Kanzaki's design had a lot too it, so hers gave me the most trouble.
>   At this stage, the cut of her jeans was only partway.  (Continued from
>   Stiyl's rough) When I read the first draft of Volume 1, I came away
>   with the impression that it was the story of children rebelling
>   against the reasoning of adults.  That is why I thought Kamijou would
>   have seen Stiyl and Kanzaki as adults that used reasonings and
>   principles that a child would refuse to accept.  At the time, I never
>   thought Index would continue this long, so I went with my impression
>   of the two and gave them designs that did not really match their
>   ages...and by about Volume 7 I was starting to regret it.